# Is there a way to have all the outline to be in black after using "subtract" blending mode?

Tags: qgis, vector, overlay, display

I have created a map of Central Africa which has two different layers: one layer shows the administrative boundaries of countries while the other one shows administrative boundaries of local regions of each country. When I overlayed the layers, I could only see the boundaries of local regions and not countries. For that reason, I used "subtract" blending mode for layer to be able to display both country and local region administrative boundaries. The issue is now that the country administrative boundaries is partial black. How can I make all the boundary to be black? Below is a screenshot of how my map map currently looks:

[image: Central Africa Map]

The map shows languages spoken in each region. Each color represents a specific language.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can achieve this without using the blending mode.

Put the country layer above the detailed polygon layer.

Style the country layer, click the triangle beside the `fill color` and select `transparent fill` at the top.

[image]

Comment: Good answer. Instead of using transparency on fill, you can also just change the "fill style" to "no brush".

Comment: Both ways worked perfectly.